# Vantagens de usar Slot no Vue.js

Tags: html5, vue.js

Qual a vantagem de se utilizar a diretiva slot no Vue.JS?

Eu posso criar itens com informações diferentes, porém, mas se eu passar um array com diversos objetos diferentes e pega-los para imprimir na tela não é diferente... Claro, no meu campo de visão que sou amador...

Pode parecer besteira, mas o slot realmente tem algum benefício, quais são?

De acordo com a documentação:

> Vue implementa uma API de distribuição de conteúdo que é modelada após
>   o atual detalhamento da especificação dos componentes da Web, usando o
>   elemento  para servir como **saída de distribuição de conteúdos**.

Digo, saída de distribuição de conteúdos a diretiva `v-for` já não faz dessa maneira?

Fonte:https://br.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html

Comment: Da uma olhada aqui, que é bem didático: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UiEqXVmHg7o&list=PLcoYAcR89n-qq1vGRbaUiV6Q9puy0qigW&index=17&t=0s

Comment: @LeAndrade eu vim de lá, por isso estou aqui rsrs. Não quero ser arrogante, mas ele não explicou a diferença e somente como usa... Não sou o primeiro a perguntar, o vídeo que me mandou tem alguns comentários com algumas dúvidas também que não foram respondidas.

Comment: Pelo que li no [post do blog](https://medium.com/the-vue-point/vue-2-6-released-66aa6c8e785e) que o criador do Vue postou a nova diretiva já é uma preparação de como vai ser no Vue 3 e tem benefícios de performance... O [RFC](https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/blob/master/active-rfcs/0001-new-slot-syntax.md) contém mais informações.

Comment: Não vou formular uma resposta porque não entendo muito a fundo o novo funcionamento, espero que o material te ajude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A diretiva slot serve principalmente para customizar partes do componente de forma mais prática, ou seja, vamos supor que você possui um card e esse card possui um footer padrão com botões de Salvar ou Cancelar, porém surgiu a necessidade de você utilizar o card com outros botões no rodapé, bom, para evitar que você fique adicionando vários ifs no cartão para atender o uso você pode simplesmente adicionar o slot, onde é possível injetar o que quiser no rodapé.